# how to use Promise with express in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, synchronous

I am using Promise with Express.

```
router.post('/Registration', function(req, res) {
  var Promise = require('promise');
  var errorsArr = [];
  function username() {
    console.log("1");
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
          reject(err)
        } else {
          console.log("2");
          errorsArr.push({ msg: "Username already been taken." });
          resolve(errorsArr);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  var username = username();
  console.log(errorsArr);
});
```

When I log `errorsArray`, it is empty and I don't know why. I am new in node.js. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `username = username();` is surely not what you want.

Comment: Yes, you are retuning a Promise. We will need to do something like `username.then(function(data){console.log(...)});`

Comment: can you please re-write it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Bergi than what should i do ?

Comment: Do you understand the concept of a Promise? Because it looks that first you will need to understand some concepts behind it...

Comment: i am getting confuse :-/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try the following, and after please read the following document https://www.promisejs.org/ to understand how the promises work.

```
var Promise = require('promise');
router.post('/Registration',function(req,res,next) {
    function username() {
        console.log("agyaaa");
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            User.findOne({"username":req.body.username}, function(err,user) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("yaha b agyaaa");
                    var errorsArr = [];
                    errorsArr.push({"msg":"Username already been taken."});
                    resolve(errorsArr);
                }

            });
        });
    }
    username().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        next();
    });
});
```

You can have other errors also (or things that shouldn't be done that way). I'm only showing you the basic use of a Promise.

Comment: No, @stackdave, it does not as of Node v0.12 (!) - see [node.green](http://node.green/#ES2015-built-ins-Promise).

Comment: @anolsi but how do you write your data into res after the promise has resolved? Express is returning res as soon as the function exits.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini I never used Express, but for what I see, you only need to use the next function. See my new edited example.

Comment: I'm surprised that you don't pass back the promise to some express handler that is going to make sure the `then` is called. Don't we need "something" to wait over the promise?

Answer (score 1):

```
router.post('/Registration', function(req, res) {
    return User
        .findOne({ username: req.body.username })
        .then((user) => {
            if (user) {
                return console.log({ msg:"Username already been taken" });
            }
            return console.log({ msg: "Username available." });
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            return console.error(err);
        });
});
```

you can write a clean code like this.
Promise is a global variable available you don't need to require it.

Comment: Thanks but why do we return a result of console.log() which is undefined?  What's the role of next() that we do not call?