# Catching all errors in async-await express route handlers

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

Suppose I have a route like this:

```
app.get('/broken', (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('Broken!');
});
```

This will never send a response to clients.

However, I can add a middleware for all errors:

```
const errorMiddleware = (error, req, res, next) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500)
      .json({
        message: 'Internal server error', 
      });
  }
  next(error);
};
```

But this will not work for `async` routes, because they do not `throw` directly.

For example, this will not work:

```
app.get('/broken', async (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('Broken!');
});
```

So I can create a wrapper like this:

```
const asyncRoute = f => (req, res, next) => {
  return Promise.resolve(f(req, res, next)).catch(next);
};

app.get('/broken', asyncRoute(async (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('Broken!');
}));
```

But this is a real pain, because now I have to call this function for every route!

What is a better way of handling this?

---

- The answer to [Is there a way to wrap an await/async try/catch block to every function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349331/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-an-await-async-try-catch-block-to-every-function) is just what I describe above
- The answer to [how to use Promise with express in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034506/how-to-use-promise-with-express-in-node-js) does not use `await`

Comment: What benefit do you think you're getting from making the route callback `async`? Express doesn't use the promise, so... Is it purely to get `await` semantics within it? If so, your wrapper is the right way to do that.

Comment: (You might look at [Koa](http://koajs.com).)

Comment: Well some of my routes require multiple `async` calls (e.g. databases, APIs, bcrypt) and therefore are easier to write in an `async` context.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. So your wrapper is the way to do that. You could do `const appGet = handler => app.get(asyncRoute(handler));` once, and then use `appGet(async (req, rest) { ... });` as necessary.

Comment: Side note: Your `asyncRoute` is creating a promise for no reason. Instead: `const asyncRoute = f => f(req, res, next).catch(next);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If I do not pass a promise (e.g. `123`) then I want a promise to be forced (e.g. `Promise.resolve(123)`). Note that `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(x))` is flattened to `Promise.resolve(x)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, Koa looks better but it is too late for my current project!

Comment: Okay. I didn't see any reason for passing a non-promise into something called `asyncRoute`, so I didn't realize you wanted to handle that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, you don't want to directly pass an `async` function into Express's `app.get`, because `app.get` doesn't handle the promise the function returns. So you'll need to wrap those `async` handlers (as you're doing).

You can avoid having to do it every time by giving yourself a utility method at the top of the module:

```
const appGet = handler => app.get(asyncRoute(handler));
```

then use it instead of `app.get`:

```
appGet('/broken', async (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('Broken!');
});
```

---

At some point (probably not right now), you might want to look at [Koa](http://koajs.com/).